# Flutter error: Each child must be laid out exactly once. On building layout

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bloc

I'm using flutter_bloc.

I've got code like this:

```
class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("SomeApp",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: myBlue.shade50,

          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.download,color:  Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DownloadView()),
                );
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chevronCircleLeft,color:  Colors.white),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainWindow()),
                );
              },
            ),]
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new BlocBuilder<SettingsBloc, SettingsState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is SettingsNotLoaded) {
              return new Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'count1',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,color: Colors.black),
                  )
              );
            } else if (state is SettingsLoaded) {  
              return new Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'count2',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,color: Colors.black),
                  )
              );
            }
            else
              {
                return new Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'count3',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0,color: Colors.black),
                    )
                );
              }
          },
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```

And when starting my app I see the appBar just the way I want, but I do not see any text in body (I should see either count1, count2 or count3), but instead I get the error:

> Each child must be laid out exactly once." referring to line 5 - `return new Scaffold(`

Of course, I looked for info on flutter_bloc page, on https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/tutorial ,here and in google as well.

Comment: what happened if you remove the `BlocBuilder` first?

Comment: if i remove whole bloc pattern with blocBuilder and just put text widget everything works fine

Comment: any fix on this? It happened to me too

Comment: have you debugged it to see the value of state? new is opetional

Answer (score 52):

I just had the same problem I think its just a bug in flutter. Stop and then reinstall your app

Answer (score 31):

Recently I had the same error.

In my case the error was caused by nesting two **Expanded Widgets** into each other.

The error has gone by removing the parent **Expanded Widget**.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue also

Comment: People should give more importance to this answer, this is indeed the problem that message tries to warns us up, anything about cleaning the cache up does work only due a concidence, this message PRECISELY warns you about the problem with your widgets.

Comment: It just works, the comment above @Renan Borges, you cannot be more right.

Comment: The same problem, Deleting the two expanded ones that I had fixes the problem.

Answer (score 25):

It's not a bug from flutter, I had faced the same issue, although the above solution is correct it seems to fail sometimes.

Try the following command

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

then run again

```
flutter run
```

or

alternatively, if you're on Android Studio (flutter plugins enabled)

Go to Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean

then run the app again,
will do the same as the above commands

After being familiar with Flutter for about a week, now I do understand that making changes in code such as adding in a new dependency in pubspec.yaml requires stopping the app and Running again, I did notice that the GUI in the IDE (I use Android Studio) might have some issue, the above commands in the command line works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

### How to fix

```java
flutter clean
```

Works fine for me, although it can be reproduced

### What triggers it in my case

This started for me since I implemented `Streams` in my application.

I'm assuming that by using a `StreamController` and making a change to what ever listens to that stream it produces the error on runtime, combined with a  `StreamBuilder` that I return to a `Widget`.

Code that reproduces the error:

```dart
  Widget passwordField(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.getPasswordStream,
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          return TextField(
            onChanged: bloc.addPasswordStream,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'password',
                labelText: 'password',
                errorText: snapshot.error
            ),
          );
        }
     );
  }
```

For example:

1. Changes some code to an already opened **stream** (ig: stream input validators)
2. Saves the application (assume the emulator is already opened)
3. Error reproduced

---

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Did you find a way to fix this without doing flutter clean every time?

Answer (score 3):

**Try the following:**

1. Stop the simulation.
2. Go to Android virtual device manager.
3. Go to "Action" in the virtual device.
4. Click the down arrow to see the option.
5. Click "wipe data"
6. Run the simulation again.

> It worked with me for Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when i performed a hot reload, then i performed a hot restart and it went away. Looks like a Flutter bug.

Answer (score 1):

**GetX State Management Specific**

In my case, I was wrapping a widget with GetX. I just remove it and used Obx for managing the state.

Comment: yeah dude the is good point but if you use Obx it's not working well like GetBuilder

Comment: obx works perfectly , as  getx document , obx better to use for streams instead of getbuilder @ahmedmohamedabdulkadir

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I used async-await on `initState()`. removing it fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem and I noticed that using hot reload number of times  pushes only modifications in my designs or any stored sqlite data.

1. So In my cases deleting stored data from app. (clearing all the caches) and
2. running flutter clean worked

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I did the following:

1. Uninstalled the application from the device
2. flutter clean
3. flutter run

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. stop the program
2. adb uninstall "$yourPackageName"
3. flutter clean
4. run the program again

You can find the name of your package in "android/app/build.gradle" => defaultConfig/applicationId

Obs: Also remember that this will only work if the problem that caused thos error has already been solved.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this bug in iOS simulator, uninstalling and re-installing the app worked for me. This happens when we use hot reload too much.

My Flutter version : `Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-2.0.pre.66, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-LK)` and I'm using android studio to build

Answer (score 0):

This error might happen under the following conditions:

- You use **Navigator 2.0**
- You use `ChildBackButtonDispatcher`
- You Hot Reload your app
- You forgot to take priority in `build` method:

```dart
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  HomeRouterDelegate _routerDelegate;
  final _state = HomeState();

  ChildBackButtonDispatcher _backButtonDispatcher;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _routerDelegate = HomeRouterDelegate(_state);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _backButtonDispatcher = Router.of(context)
        .backButtonDispatcher
        .createChildBackButtonDispatcher();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The app will throw an exception 'Each child must be laid out exactly once.'
    // without this line on each Hot Reload
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/66258147/1321917
    _backButtonDispatcher.takePriority();
    return Router(
      routerDelegate: _routerDelegate,
      backButtonDispatcher: _backButtonDispatcher,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Track the logs in the debug console and under that error, you might see a log saying:

```
The stack when the error occurred was:
.............
.............
.............
```

Read these lines carefully to know which code is the problem!

Comment: i need to call you, could you give me any social media to contact you through, please?

Comment: You can contact me via LinkedIn:  https://www.linkedin.com/in/ahmedatab
Or by email on:
atab.ahmad98@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Widget which using padding should not be parent widget of any builder widget. Remove padding. And wrap widget inside builder with padding or wrap builder with SizedBox or Container or any.

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main()=> runApp(BMIcalculatro());

class BMIcalculatro extends StatelessWidget {

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(



  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(

    primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),


    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),

  ),

  home: InputPage(),

) ;

} }



const activColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);



const inActiveColor = Color(0XFF111328);



enum Gender{




male, female



}



class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {




@override



_InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();



}



class _InputPageState extends State {



Gender genderSelected;



@override



Widget build(BuildContext context) {




return Scaffold(



    appBar: AppBar(



      title: Text('BMIcalculator'),



      centerTitle: true,



    ),

    body: Column(



      children: [



        Expanded(




          child: Row(



            children: [



              Expanded(




                child: GestureDetector(



                  onTap: () {



                    setState(() {



                      genderSelected=Gender.male;



                    });




                  },



                  child: ReusableCard(





                    colour: genderSelected ==Gender.male ? activColor: inActiveColor,



                    cardChaild: IconrContakt(



                      icone: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,



                      name: "MAIL",



                    ),


                  ),

                ),

              ),

              Expanded(



                child: GestureDetector(



                  onTap: () {




                    setState(() {



                       genderSelected=Gender.female;



                    });

                  },

                  child: ReusableCard(



                    colour: genderSelected==Gender.female ? activColor:inActiveColor,



                    cardChaild: IconrContakt(




                      icone: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,



                      name: "female",

                    ),

                  ),


                ),


              ),

            ],

          ),

        ),

        Expanded(



          child: Expanded(



            child: ReusableCard(



              colour: activColor,


            ),
          ),

        ),
        Expanded(



          child: Row(



            children: [



              Expanded(



                  child: ReusableCard(



                colour: activColor,



              )),

              Expanded(



                child: ReusableCard(



                  colour: activColor,



                ),

              ),

            ],

          ),

        ),

        Container(



          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),



          decoration: BoxDecoration(



            color: Color(0xFFEB1555),



          ),

          child: Center(



              child: Text(



            'BMI CALCULATOR',



            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),



          )),

          width: double.infinity,



          height: 80.0,



        )

      ],

    ),

    );

} }



class IconrContakt extends StatelessWidget {



IconrContakt({this.icone, this.name});



final IconData icone;



final String name;



@override



Widget build(BuildContext context) {



return Column(



  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,



  children: [



    Icon(



      icone,



      size: 80,



    ),

    SizedBox(



      height: 15,



    ),

    Text(



      name,



      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),



    )

  ],

);

} }



class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {



ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChaild});



final Color colour;



final Widget cardChaild;



@override



Widget build(BuildContext context) {



return Container(



  child: cardChaild,



  margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),



  decoration: BoxDecoration(



    color: colour,



    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.3),



  ),

);

} }
```

And here is the error

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
>
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5022 pos 16: >'child
>
> is!'
>
> ParentDataElement': is not true.'
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold
> lib\home.dart:23
>
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════

Each child must be laid out exactly once.

The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold.

Answer (score -1):

I've got this error when referencing `widget` in the `State`'s constructor:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget(this.data, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final String data;

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  _MyWidgetState() {
    debugPrint(widget.data); // This line causes error.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```