# Facing "Each child must be laid out exactly once. The relevant error-causing widget was: Scaffold" error in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

cause of the scaffold the bottom navigation bar is not responding and the App UI just entered a while loop
1: it appears the circular progress I made
2: I should give this app this week
3: am new to flutter

So I'd like to ask all of you, maybe someone will be able to explain to me why I get that error, what does it mean, and how to get rid of it.

any answers for this problem ?

```dart
import 'package:MeeM/pages/notification.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/Home.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/search.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/add/add.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/profileUI/profile.dart';
import 'package:MeeM/pages/signup_page.dart';

// ignore: camel_case_types
class nav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _navState createState() => _navState();
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _navState extends State<nav> {
  int _currentindex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgeroption = <Widget>[
    Home(currentUser: currentUser),
    search(),
    add(currentUser: currentUser),
    notification(),
    profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
  ];

  void _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentindex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentindex,
        children: _widgeroption,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'search',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add_box_outlined,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'upload',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'feed',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 30,
            ),
            label: 'profile',
          ),
        ],
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        currentIndex: _currentindex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
~~~!
```

Comment: This may happen due to same caching issue, try to stop the app, run ```flutter clean``` and run it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be an error in your `Child` components in `_widgeroption`. for example, check that you have not used two same widgets (like `Expanded` widget) as a nested widget.
If not, it can be due to the caching process of `Flutter`. do these steps:

1. in the command line enter `flutter clean` and press enter.
2. then run `flutter pub get`
3. and finally run `flutter run`

for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076949/flutter-error-each-child-must-be-laid-out-exactly-once-on-building-layout).

Comment: that was great thanks

Comment: @AbderrezakDouba happy to help. If my answer helped you, I would be grateful if you tag it as a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace this:

```dart
 body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentindex,
        children: _widgeroption,
      ),
```

by this:

```dart
 body: IndexedStack(
        index: _currentindex,
        children: <Widget>[
           Home(currentUser: currentUser),
           search(),
           add(currentUser: currentUser),
           notification(),
           profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
        ],
      ),
```

The widgets in `children` have to rebuild when you call `setState` but the predefined `_widgeroption` can't rebuild because it's outside the `build` method.

You can also define the `_widgeroption` inside the `build` method to make it works:

```dart
[...]
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _widgeroption = <Widget>[
      Home(currentUser: currentUser),
      search(),
      add(currentUser: currentUser),
      notification(),
      profile(profileId: currentUser?.id),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
[...]
```